# Remove/Clear localStorage inside of the Excel Add In

Tags: javascript, excel-addins

I developed a sideloaded Excel Add In. There I used the localStorage to save values throughout the whole session.

Is there a way to empty the localStorage inside of excel. I know that the browser is not Chrome and Firefox inside of Excel. **I red through the whole documentation and couldn't find a way besides reload the instance which does not clear the localStorage!**

Offical documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your scenario, have you try `.clear()`, it can clear the Browser long-term storage

```
localStorage.clear();
```

If you want to have short term storage, you may use `sessionStorage`, then you may dont have to clear the storage.

Comment: Something like that, but without changing the code base, but there is no dev tools in the side loaded add in.

Comment: I am interested in your scenario, do you mean you want to clean the localStorage via Excel UI?

Comment: Correct. Like to reset the state of the Add In.

Comment: You could create a button in your add-in, add the code to clean the localStorage. I dont think we have UI to clean the localStorage, as the localStorage used by add-in is important to add-in end users.